# PC boot loop bug, how to enter bios if none of the 'F' keys work?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, boot, windows-8.1, bios

A laptop (Samsung NP270) was running OK but after several Windows updates on windows 8.1 it started an endless boot loop, showing 2 screens

- First screen: Windows logo
- Second screen: BSOD saying windows found an error and it was going to reboot.

None of the 'F' keys worked for entering the BIOS setup. So I removed the HDD, and powered up the computer, a black screen showed saying that if i should press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter something like a recovery mode, but I was unable to enter the BIOS screen setup to enable a boot from a Windows 8.1 recovery flash USB that I've created. I plugged the HDD into a USB case and connected on another computer, I backed up up some files i would need, and now I two options:

OP 1

- How to make the laptop read the flash USB drive (windows 8.1 recovery flash USB) if I am unable to open the bios setup screen? Do I need to remove the CMOS battery and wait for its content vanish? If I can do this I can recover windows 8.1

OP 2

- How do I do a fresh install of Windows 10 on the laptop HDD connected to a USB port of another computer? (This seems to be the best way, without having to mess with BIOS setup, since the boot is set to be first on HDD).

Comment: The F keys are required to either enter the recovery mode or change the boot order so your flash drive can be booted to. Are you sure the laptop doesn't use the Function + F keys to get an F key to be recognized? Laptops commonly require the function key and an F key at the same time.

Comment: @Narzard none of the keys work, it appears to be a bug with this kind of Samsung laptop

Comment: @ crawletas Your only option might be to grab a usb keyboard

Comment: Windows 8.1 will automatically after three failed attempts to boot into Windows present you the Advanced Startup.  Advanced Startup is how you access the firmware settings in all versions of Windows after 8 running in UEFI mode.

Comment: @Ramhound No "advanced setup" screen is showing, even after 30 reboots, it is endless

Comment: You might have to force it to crash before the stage where a BSOD is being displayed, that is because, if you are seeing a BSOD then Windows has already semi-booted.

Comment: @Ramhound how do I do that?

Comment: You should also try the "delete" key

Comment: @Jarco doesn't work either

Comment: many modern laptops swap the Function and Media keys, so you might need to press Fn in order to get the Function keys